# Intuitive explanation of convection in a closed volume

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, convection

I am trying to wrap my head around what happens when say a hollow cylinder containing a gas is heated from the bottom.

Intuitively I know that the gas in the cylinder will heat up, expand and pressure will develop. I am trying to understand the various processes that take place causing this.

So far, my reasoning seems to be:

1. The bottom of the cylinder heats the layer of gas in contact by conduction
2. Heated layer expands, dropping its density
3. Lower density causes it to experience a buoyant force
4. Force causes the lower density pocket of gas to experience acceleration, drag and a resultant velocity.

... and here is where my thought process starts to break down.

An intuitive explanation (or a resource that explains it) would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct! And welcome to the stack exchange.

Here is what you might be missing in this picture.

Imagine you hold by a string a balloon full of helium. Because the helium is *less dense* than the air that surrounds it, gravity pulls down on the air above it harder and the balloon experiences an upward *buoyant force* which makes it want to rise. And if you let go of the string, the balloon rises.

Now imagine the balloon holds hot air instead of helium. The exact same thing will happen: when you let go of the string, up goes the balloon.

Finally, imagine that the balloon wall thickness goes to zero i.e., the volume of hot air is immersed in a larger mass of cooler air. The air above this "bubble" of hot air is denser than the bubble, so that cooler air wants to sink below the bubble and the bubble wants to rise. UP goes the bubble.

In this bubble case, the cooler air is free to get mixed with the hot air as they move past one another, and after a while the bubble dissipates and stops rising.

But as long as there is a hot surface below it in the container which continues to heat more air, that hot air will continue to rise and as it does, cool air from nearby will be moved into contact with the hot surface and a *convection cell* will be set up, which continuously mixes up the air in the container and guarantees heat transfer from the hot surface to all the air inside the container.